# Show / Hide element by data attribute (react=

Tags: reactjs

How can i show/hide elements in a list using react? I have buttons with data-attribute
and i want when click show elements with this classname and hide the others.

example here:

[image: example here]

```
class ModelosItems extends React.Component {
  handleCheck(e) {
    console.log(e.currentTarget.dataset.gama );
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <section className="section">
        <div className="container">
          <h2 className="title is-size-4 has-text-centered is-uppercase has-text-weight-bold">Gama kia</h2>
          <div className="tabs-container">
              <div className="fade"></div>
              <div className="tabs">
                  <ul>
                      <li className="is-active"><a href="/" onClick={this.handleCheck.bind(this)} data-gama="todos">Gama Completa</a></li>
                      <li><a href="/" onClick={this.handleCheck.bind(this)} data-gama="citadinos_familiares">Cidatidos e Familiares</a></li>
                      <li><a href="/" onClick={this.handleCheck.bind(this)} data-gama="suv_crossovers">Suv e Crossover</a></li>
                    </ul>
              </div>
          </div>
          <ModelsList />
        </div>
      </section>
    );
  }
};

export default ModelosItems;
```

Thank you!

Comment: You want to show/hide these `<li>` items? Or the items within `<ModelsList />` component?

Comment: items within <ModelsList /> component @Kox

Comment: Hi Diego, for someone to provide you with good example of how you can do that, you need to also provide `<ModelsList />` content as well.

Comment: hi @ggat, i just want add style "display:none" to elements don't have the value passed in data attribute

Answer (score 0):

For hide the other datas and just show the special data, you have to filter your list. After, you can for example, add a CSS class whose this class hide the other datas, and you'll have just your special data showed.

A tutorial : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HqQ-kOchqHM

Answer (score 0):

Utilize local state for this. Initialize it with the first value (probably `todos`) and update it when you select another type correspondingly.

Next, pass this state data attribute to `ModelsList` component as a prop and simply filter the items within the list.

Answer (score 0):

Introduce state to `ModelosItems`

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {currentGama: null};
}
```

on click update state

```
handleCheck(e) {
  this.setState({
    currentGama: e.currentTarget.dataset.gama
  });
}
```

Add new prop to `ModelosItems` `gama` and feed `currentGama` state value to it

```
<ModelsList gama={this.state.gama} />
```

In your `ModelList` component, I'm guessing here

`cars.filter(car => car.gama === this.props.gama).map(...`

this will result in rendering only cars that have right gama. This does not use classnames to hide cars. But I think this is what you need.